# Django: assign value for field in model class during instantiation

Tags: django, django-models, initialization

I can do this:

```
counter = 0

class A(models.Model):
  code = models.IntegerField(max_length=30, default=generate_code)

def generate_code():
  counter += 1
  return counter
```

But it seems to be, that the assignment is done during the initialization (loading) of the model class, not at creating an instance, so 'code' is always '1'.

How can I automatically assign a dynamic value to some field during creating an instance of a model class?

If I set the value in an overriden `__init__` function, like this:

```
class A(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.code = self.generate_code()
```

The code is change on every update. As the debugger shows me, the  `__init__` function is also called, when I delete the object. I really do not understand this!

I can set the code in the `__init__` function only, if it is not set, but that seems to be illogical, so I like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for a way to make sure that each of the A objects in your database has a unique counter value? Then you can use `AutoField` instead of `IntegerField`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField

When you create a new `A` object, its `counter` value will be automatically set to one higher than the previously created one.

To explain some of the behavior you're seeing, each time your models.py is loaded, it will indeed initialize a new `counter` variable to 0, as you figured out. As for why the `A` constructor is being called when you don't expect it, `A` is just a class representing some data from the database. So every time Django gets data out of the database and presents it to you, it's creating a new `A` object to encapsulate that data.

Comment: Okay, that sounds logically regarding `__init__`. I think, I have found the solution for my problem: I have to override the `save` function and set `code`, if it is not already set. The `AutoField` does not fit my problem, because I need a random value not an incrementing one. (Sorry, I have simplified my example too much.)